# Why isn't the variable returned?

Tags: python, return

I created the following code to implement K-means clustering as Python.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt("k-mean-input.dat")

numlist_x = list(range(-8, 15, 1))
numlist_y = list(range(-13, 12, 1))

random_node_1 = [random.choice(numlist_x), random.choice(numlist_y)]
random_node_2 = [random.choice(numlist_x), random.choice(numlist_y)]
random_node_3 = [random.choice(numlist_x), random.choice(numlist_y)]

def distance(a, b):
    result = np.sqrt((a[0] - b[0])**2 + (a[1] - b[1])**2)
    return result

def center_readjustment(matrix, random_node):
    total_x = 0
    total_y = 0
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        total_x += matrix[i][0]
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        total_y += matrix[i][1]
        
    new_node_x = total_x / len(matrix)
    new_node_y = total_y / len(matrix)
    if not (new_node_x, new_node_y) == random_node:
        random_node = ((new_node_x, new_node_y))
        print(random_node)
        return random_node
    else:
        end = True

def main0(data, random_node_1, random_node_2, random_node_3):

    print(random_node_1, random_node_2, random_node_3)
    plt.scatter(random_node_1[0], random_node_1[1], color = 'red', marker = 'x')
    plt.scatter(random_node_2[0], random_node_2[1], color = 'green', marker = 'x')
    plt.scatter(random_node_3[0], random_node_3[1], color = 'blue', marker = 'x')

    first = []
    second = []
    third = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        if distance(random_node_1, data[i]) <= distance(random_node_2, data[i]) and distance(random_node_1, data[i]) <= distance(random_node_3, data[i]):
                first.append(data[i])
        elif distance(random_node_2, data[i]) <= distance(random_node_1, data[i]) and distance(random_node_2, data[i]) <= distance(random_node_3, data[i]):
                second.append(data[i])
        elif distance(random_node_3, data[i]) <= distance(random_node_1, data[i]) and distance(random_node_3, data[i]) <= distance(random_node_2, data[i]):
                third.append(data[i])

    for i in range(len(first)):
            plt.scatter(first[i][0], first[i][1], color = 'red', s = 10)
    for i in range(len(second)):
            plt.scatter(second[i][0], second[i][1], color = 'green', s = 10)
    for i in range(len(third)):
            plt.scatter(third[i][0], third[i][1], color = 'blue', s = 10)

    plt.show()

    center_readjustment(first, random_node_1)
    center_readjustment(second, random_node_2)
    center_readjustment(third, random_node_3)

    print(random_node_1)

end = False

main0(data, random_node_1, random_node_2, random_node_3)
```

Random_node must be readjusted to repeat the main function by putting the while statement, but the changed center point comes out properly in the print in the center_readjustment, but printing random_node_1 in the main0 function produces the initial value and does not change.

I made random_node return in the center_readjustment function, but random_node_1 in main0 does not change.

How can I change random_node_1 from main0 function to adjusted value from center_readjustment?

Comment: You need to capture the return of your function back to a variable, like: `random_node_1 = center_readjustment(first, random_node_1)`. Otherwise that return is just discarded and superfluous.